# How to use spaces in a "variable name"?

Tags: c, string, variables

I have a very simple question but i just started learning C. I'd really appreciate if i could get some help because i'm trying to understand how the syntax works in the language.

What i want to do is something like this

```
    int Score1, Score2, "Final Score";
```

the error message i get is this:

```
    error: expected identifier or '(' before string constant
```

Comment: `"Final Score"` is a value (type: string or char*) by the way, not a variable name. The quotes (`"`) works like a value assignment. Just like `6` would be, which is invalid as a variable name as well.

Comment: "What i want to do is something like this" is not a meaningful explanation of the meaning that you want to assign to your `"Final Score"` entry. What is it doing there? What is the intended effect supposed to be?

Comment: Does calling the variable `Final_Score` fail to meet your need somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to define a variable with a name that contains a blank character you cannot do it.

You should try removing the quotes with the variable name final_score .

Answer (score 6):

In general (and definitely in C), variable names must be valid identifiers<sup>1</sup> and *cannot* contain spaces or quotation marks.

Consider naming the variable `finalScore` or `final_score` instead.

---

<sup>1</sup> The syntax of an identifier is succinctly given in [The C Programming Language (K&R)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language), A.2.3 Identifiers:

> An identifier is a sequence of letters [a-z, A-Z, _] and digits [0-9]. The first character must be a letter; the underscore _ counts as a letter ..

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean:

int score1, score2, final_score;

Answer (score 1):

A variable name in C can contain any combination of alphabets, numbers and under-score (_).
Any other special characters are not allowed in variable name.

Removing double quotes and using final_score or finalScore will work.

Also note that you can't have a variable name legal if it starts with a digit, although it can start with under-score

Answer (score -1):

C, along with many other programming languages, don't allow any spaces, and some other special characters in variable names. You can however say something like: finalScore, or final_score

Comment: This has already been mentioned in the other answers.